# Function defined in a service is not a function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller Device Controller. I am trying to access a function in service but I am getting an error -
TypeError: DeviceService1.addNewDevice is not a function
    at ChildScope.$scope.submitDeviceDtls (CreateDeviceCtrl.js:175)

Here's my code

```
    $scope.submitDeviceDtls = function () {

                if ($scope.isNewDevice) {
                    DeviceService1.addNewDevice($scope.device).then(
                        function (res) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                            // logic
                          }
                        }
                     }
```

I have a service DeviceService1

```
   function ($http, $q, ApiService, AuthService) {

        return {

            addNewDevice: function (deviceDtls) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var payload = new FormData();

                payload.append('deviceDtls', new Blob([JSON
                    .stringify(deviceDtls)], {
                    type: "application/json"
                }));
                // payload.append('profilePic', profile_pic);
                payload.append('doctorId', AuthService.getDoctorId());
                var req = {

                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    },
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                    data: payload
                }

                ApiService.generic_post('/device/', req).then(
                    function (res) {

                        deferred.resolve(res);

                    }, function (error) {

                        deferred.reject(error);
                    }
                );

                return deferred.promise;

            }

 return DeviceService1;
```

Can someone help me? TIA

Comment: Do you mean export DeviceService1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your DeviceService1 you are returning firstly an object with the properties you need which includes the function (`addnewDevice`) you are trying to call but afterwards you return DeviceService1 (`return DeviceService`) which overrides the first return.

Just remove the following part:

`return DeviceService1;`